# Программа запоминающая все нажатия клавиш с момента включения ПК

Tags: java, события, клавиатура

Хочу написать программу для запоминания всех клавиш нажатых с момента включения пк(интересуют видимые символ т.е по поводу спец клавиш можно не заморачиваться).

Пробовал сделать это с при помощи обработчика событий на `СВИНГЕ`, но при сворачивании окна данные больше не записывались,

БУДУ РАД ЛЮБОЙ ИДУИ ПО РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ

```
public class start extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame jFrame = getFrame();
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    jFrame.add(jPanel);

    JButton jButton = new JButton("dgfrfgr");
    jPanel.add(jButton);

    GraphicsEnvironment environment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice device = environment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(1000, 300);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

    jButton.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.print(e.getKeyChar());
            try(FileWriter writer =  new FileWriter("result.txt", true)){   
                writer.write(e.getKeyChar());
            }
            catch(IOException e1){
                System.out.println("Dont write");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    });

    jPanel.revalidate();
}

static JFrame getFrame(){
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setBounds(750, 250, 500, 500);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    return jFrame;
}
}
```

Comment: Решения вашей проблемы не знаю, но попробуйте погуглить в сторону `global hotkey java`. Плюс, программа, которую вы хотите написать, называется `keylogger` и возможно вас устроят уже существующие аналоги.

Comment: Кейлоггеры на Java не пишут.